# A clone_ptr<T> that does not require T to have a clone method

Tags: c++, pointers

Here is my clone pointer template:

```
#include <functional>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct clone_ptr
{
    clone_ptr() : ptr(nullptr), cloner(nullptr) {}
    clone_ptr(clone_ptr&& other) noexcept
        : clone_ptr()
    {
        swap( other );
    }
    clone_ptr(const clone_ptr& other)
    {
        ptr = other.cloner(other.ptr);
        cloner = other.cloner;
    }
    void swap( clone_ptr& other ) noexcept
    {
        using std::swap;
        swap( ptr,    other.ptr    );
        swap( cloner, other.cloner );
    }

    clone_ptr& operator=( const clone_ptr& other )
    {
        clear();
        ptr = other.cloner(other.ptr);
        cloner = other.cloner;
        return *this;
    }
    clone_ptr& operator=( clone_ptr&& other )
    {
        clear();
        swap(other);
        return *this;
    }

    T* operator->() { return ptr; }
    const T* operator->() const { return ptr; }
    T& operator*() { return *ptr; }
    const T& operator*() const { return *ptr; }

    operator bool() const { return ptr; }

    bool operator<(const clone_ptr& other) const
    {
        if(!ptr) return other.ptr;
        if(!other.ptr) return false;
        return (*ptr) < (*other.ptr);
    }
    bool operator==(const clone_ptr& other) const
    {
        if(!ptr) return !other.ptr;
        if(!other.ptr) return false;
        return (*ptr) == (*other.ptr);
    }

    std::ostream& output(std::ostream& os) const { if(ptr) os << *ptr; else os << "<nullptr>"; return os ; }

    template<typename T2=T, typename ...Ts>
    void make( Ts&& ...ts )
    {
        clear();
        ptr = new T2( std::forward<Ts>(ts)... );
        cloner = [](T* p) -> T* { return new T2( * (T2*) p ); };
    }

    void clear() { delete ptr; ptr=nullptr; cloner=nullptr; }

    ~clone_ptr() { clear(); }

private:
    T* ptr;
    std::function<T*(T*)> cloner;
};

template<typename T, typename T2=T, typename ...Ts>
clone_ptr<T> make_cloned( Ts&& ...ts )
{
    clone_ptr<T> p;
    p.template make<T2>( std::forward<Ts>(ts)... );
    return p;
}

template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const clone_ptr<T>& p) { return p.output(os); }
```

It is primarily intended to preserve polymorphism, esp. when stored in a container. It "forwards" `operator<` and `operator==` so containers can be sorted etc. based on the contained object.

Have I missed/forgotten anything?

Comment: Final draft [here](http://pastebin.com/1pXbEu6H). Feel free to use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have only a few minor issues with the code.

For your `operator=`, you might want to use the usual copy-and-swap idiom. If not, you should check for self-assignment, as this will currently break very badly on something like `a = a` (as silly as that is, it can happen, and should be guarded against).

Your `operator bool` should be `explicit`. This is obviously intended to be used as something like `if(some_cloned_ptr)` for `nullptr` checks. Currently, this will allow sillyness like `bool b = some_pointer`. At least with `explicit`, this will require an actual cast. I'd also probably change this to `return ptr != nullptr`.

Your `make_cloned` template feels like it should probably have a `static_assert` in there using `std::is_convertible<T, T2>` to give nicer error messages in the case that it fails.

Answer (score 3):

### Prefer to use Copy and Swap Idiom

```
clone_ptr& operator=( const clone_ptr& other )
{
    clear();
    ptr = other.cloner(other.ptr);
    cloner = other.cloner;
    return *this;
}
```

Or

```
clone_ptr& operator=(clone_ptr copy)
{
    copy.swap(*this);
    return *this;
}
```

### No need to clear on move assignment

```
clone_ptr& operator=( clone_ptr&& other )
{
    // clear();   No need to do that.
                  The destructor of `other` will do that at some point.
    swap(other);
    return *this;
}
```

Easier to write as:

```
clone_ptr& operator=(clone_ptr copy)
{
    copy.swap(*this);
    return *this;
}
```

### Personally I don't see the point in havin output() and operator<<

I would just combine them into `operator<<` and make it a friend (also declare it in the class).

Comment: The `operator<` comparison is comparing the underlying values, not the pointers themselves.